# Symbolic Maximization: does not work with symbolic power?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, symbolic

Simple question from a beginner: I seem to be unable to do maximization if the variable has a power specified symbolically instead of numerically?

```
Maximize[-x^2+a*x,x]
```

But now:

```
Maximize[-x^b+a*x,x]
```

Seems to fail. Am I doing something wrong? Or can indeed Mathematica no maximize symbolically, at least with powers? Are there other cases it will fail?

And last question, does this imply I should code manually, solving the FOCs by hand?

Thanks!

Comment: You are making assumptions on `b` that are not necessarily the same as *Mathematica*; e.g. it assumes everything is complex-valued unless explicitly told otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because there is no general solution for your problem, even for `b` being a positive integer: When `b` is odd, the maximum is positive infinity, while for even `b` it is not. You may want to use things like `Maximize[-x^# + a*x, x] & /@ Table[i, {i, 5}]` to observe.

Comment: Sure, makes full sense, thanks!! This leads me to the more precise question: how can I specify the range of my "parameters" (as opposed to arguments of the function) a and b? Here I had b between 0 and 1, and a >0? As an example, I tried Maximize[{x^0.5 - a*x, x > 0, a > 0}, x] but this didn't seem to work... Thanks so much!

Comment: @Matifou  I recommend that you post a new question, rather than trying to add more material to the original question by meant of comments.